# How to speed up the INSERT request in the PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

In **PostgreSQL** database I have such table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS layers (ID NUMERIC, GEOM GEOMETRY, CITY VARCHAR, AGGREGATION_METHOD VARCHAR, INFO JSON);
```

I am tring to insert to that table `~700` records with such one query:

```
INSERT INTO layers (ID, GEOM, CITY, AGGREGATION_METHOD, INFO) VALUES
(107509018555, '0203000020E61000000100000005000000000000808531534000000020749D4540000000808531534000000080159E4540000000201731534000000080159E4540000000201731534000000020749D4540000000808531534000000020749D4540', 'New York', 'MONTHLY', '[{"time":"2019-10-01T00:00:00Z","gender_details":[{"gender":"Male"},{"gender":"Female"}]}]'),
(107509018556, '0303000020E610000001000000050000000000008085315340000000A0D29A4640000000808531534000000020749D4540000000201731534000000020749D45400000002017315340000000A0D29C45400000008085315340000000A0D29C4540', 'London', 'MONTHLY', '[{"time":"2019-10-01T00:00:00Z","gender_details":[{"gender":"Male"},{"gender":"Female"}]}]')
... other 698 values
```

That query runs for 9-10 seconds. Is there a way to speed up the insert request in the PostgreSQL database?

PostgreSQL version: 11.0 (running on Red Hat)

**Query Plan:**
[image]

Comment: 10 seconds for under 1000 rows is way too slow. Do you have maybe many triggers or foreign keys on that table? Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text) insert into layers ...`** (**not** just a "simple" explain) as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you prevent the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan.

Comment: Thank you for your tip. From query plan we can say that insert query is nornal, right?! What do you think can be optimized in this query? In fact I made that query from backend application. I found the cause of the problem in backend application. Also can you post your answer, I will mark it as correct.

Comment: As I wrote an execution plan is better show as formatted text, not hard-to-read images. But nevertheless. The plan clearly shows that the insert only took less than 3 **milli** seconds - not 10 seconds. Wherever you see those 10 seconds, it's not caused by the server, but the program you use to send the query.

Comment: That execution plan shows a total duration of the 2.3 milliseconds. Or is there a lengthy trigger execution in the part you hid?

Comment: So guys how to determine an acceptable `INSERT` time? How you know that 2.3 milliseconds is normal for under 700 rows?

Comment: You claimed it took 10 **seconds** not 2.3 milliseconds. Does your last comment mean, your new question is now: "*is an insert speed of 30.000 rows per second acceptable*"?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name in one of my previous comment I said that it's not 10 seconds. I found the problem which was in my backend application. I just generally want to know how to determine an acceptable `INSERT` time? I how you understand what I mean.

Comment: Define "acceptable"

Comment: For example in your first comment, you said that `10 seconds for under 1000 rows is way too slow`. So I want to know how many seconds or milliseconds is optimal for 1000 rows for your opinion? I understand the question is vague and depends on many details.

Comment: There is no declared official "per row" value - it could be more or less depending on the size of the data, they are just giving you educated guesses. The rows you show being inserted appear to be somewhere in the region of... 350 bytes each, multiply that by 700 you get an estimated 245,000 bytes of insert, or 239kb. Ask yourself then, would it seem reasonable for it to take 2 miliseconds to save this amount of data, or would it be reasonable to take 10 seconds? The number may vary from drive to drive, but do you understand why 10 seconds looks high now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If there any indeces or foreign keys on your table they will definetely slow down the execution. You might consider insert data into table without indeces and create ones later. Check if there any triggers as well.
2. You can also try to load data using [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-copy.html) command. It's faster than INSERT.
3. If you have slow disks this might be an issue, you can try to use an [UNLOGGED](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createtable.html) table in order to generate less WAL segments during the load operation. But please, be careful, this method has downsides as well.

Off topic: consider using [JSONB](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/datatype-json.html#JSON-CONTAINMENT) type instead of JSON.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. In my case, there are no foreign keys or indexes in the table. Also I changed the data type from `json` to `jsonb` as you recommended. From query plan I see that the query sped up a bit. I insert into the table aggregate data from different sources. For that's why I think I can use `COPY` statement. The third part of your post is interesting but defore insert I always clean the table from any data.

Comment: Can I ask you one more question? For your opinion, how to determine an acceptable `INSERT` time? For example how many seconds or milliseconds are optimal for 1000 rows for your opinion? ,

Comment: It depends on your requirements and hardware you run on. But as the rule of thumb (this works for the huge amounts of data thought) you can estimate the size of the data you're inserting and estimate the time your hardware need to write this data to the disk (using `dd` command, for instance). RDBMS shouldn't be do that slower.